# Есть ли разница между «за» и «к/ко»?

Tags: морфология, предлоги

*Здравствуйте.*

*Отличаются ли чем-нибудь друг от друга предлоги **«за»** и **«к/ко»**?*

*Например:*

*Я потянулся **за** полотенцем/Я потянулся **к** полотенцу;*

*Чудовища тянутся **за** мной уродливыми конечностями/Чудовища тянутся **ко** мне уродливыми конечностями.*

*Мне кажется, тонкое, не совсем явное различие меж этими предлогами существует.*

*Спасибо.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

За кем-чем. Указывает на лицо, предмет и т.п., которые нужно достать, добыть, привести и т.п.

Послать за врачом. Заехать за вещами. Идти за водой.

К; КО, предлог. 1. Употр. при обозначении предмета или лица как объекта действия, как места, предела, конечного пункта, в сторону которого направлено действие, движение.

Скакать к лесу. Плыть к острову. Ехать к брату. Повернуться к окну. Наклониться к ребёнку. Спуск к реке. Дорога к лесу. На подступах к городу.

Потянулся за полотенцем. Оттенок цели.

Я потянулся к полотенцу. Оттенок той же цели с направлением действия.